# How to make multiple page using jspdf

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I want to make a multiple page PDF file using jspdf library.
I used this code. But when this code is used, there is no margin(top) from 2page.
I want to make multiple page and clear margin about all pages.
Or give me a another way. this PDF make some noise.

Please help me.

```
function pdfDown(){
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("download"), {
    onrendered : function(canvas){
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var imgWidth = 190; 
      var pageHeight = 290; 
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight; 
      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
      var position = 10; 
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight; 

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
      position = heightLeft - imgHeight +13;
      doc.addPage();
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      } 
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    } 
  });
```

For your reference, I use php documentation.